# Order details by invoice_id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get order details by invoice id? I need order details by invoice id.

I got this [how to get order deatils by invoice id?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33240/how-to-get-order-deatils-by-invoice-id) but this is for magento 1

Comment: You should use factory method instead of object manager. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento2 this can be achieves as :

```
protected $objectManager;

public function __construct(
     .....
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
     .......
    ) {
     ...
     $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
     ........
   }


  public function getOrder($invoice_id){
    $invoice= $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice')->load($invoice_id);
    return $invoice->getOrder();
  }
```

Comment: you should not use the objectmanager in production though ;) better require the real class in your constructor

Answer (score 2):

**Use factory method instead of object manager**

```
protected $invoiceFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceFactory $invoiceFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->invoiceFactory = $invoiceFactory;
    ...
}

public function getOrderByInvoice($invoiceId)
{
    $invoice = $this->invoiceFactory->create()->load($invoiceId);
    return $invoice->getOrder();
}
```